# How to use scrollwheel (middle mouse button) to open link in new tab in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, catalina

Before I upgraded to Catalina, in Chrome I could just middle-click on a link to open it in a new tab. And life was great.

After upgrading to Catalina, this still works in Safari but for whatever reason, in Chrome this now performs a "back" operation.

How do I revert back to the previous behaviour?

In System Preferences > Mouse, nor in Chrome settings, do I find any reference to either "scrollwheel" or "middle mouse button".

The device I use is a Logitech wireless mouse (not sure of the exact model but the sticker on the bottom says M525-C) with 2 actual buttons and a clickable scrollwheel inbetween.

EDIT 19-NOV-2019: I noticed that an update to Chrome was available so upgraded it to `Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)`. After this I see a change in behavior, but it gets even weirder now:

- sometimes clicking the scrollwheel button behaves the way I want,
  i.e. it opens the link in a new tab
- sometimes it behaves the erratic way, i.e. it's the same as clicking "Back"
- sometimes it does both, i.e. the linked page opens in a new tab but in the original tab it goes back to the previous page?!

EDIT 20-NOV-2019:
The current behavior seems to be related to the fact that the scrollwheel cannot only be clicked, but also moved left and right. In Chrome, moving it left is the same as clicking "Back", moving it to the right is the same as clicking "Forward".
So when I click the wheel, I sometimes (often) accidentally move it slightly to the left while clicking - which explains the "sometimes it does both" part above.

When I pay special attention, I am able to click without moving left and then it works fine (opens the link a new tab), but I use(d) this feature hundreds of times a day without thinking. It really affects my workflow to have to pay special attention every time I do this.

I am absolutely sure this is not how it behaved pre-Catalina so I still hope someone can help me get back to the old behavior (where it did not matter if I slightly moved the wheel to the left while clicking).

Additional note: I've installed Logitech Control Center but it says "No Logitech device found".

Comment: Thanks, I've moved on in the meantime and replaced my Logitech mouse with an Evoluent VerticalMouse, which has an actual middle button (among other nifty features).